# Redefining \vec

Tags: math-mode, bold, vector

I have two methods to redefine `\vec` to display in bold font.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}
\renewcommand{\vec}{\mathbf}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \vec{\mu} = \vec{x}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

The first method (commented out) works fine, but the second displays `x` in bold font but displays `\mu` in normal font. Why is this the case?

Also, I am considering changing all vectors to normal font. How can I redefine `\vec` to display in normal font?

Cheers...

Comment: Use the bm package and `\bm` instead. Mathbf only targets letters not symbols, plus they end upright. Bm is bold italic, and in most cases for symbols, if a bold version does not exist, it emulates it.

Comment: @daleif that works well. What about redefining for normal font? Is     \renewcommand{\vec}{\mathnormal} an appropriate method?

Comment: No idea, and I would not, looks weird if `\vec{x} =(x_1,x_2,x_3)` has the first x in upright bold, the later in italic, they ought to have something in common

Comment: @daleif hmm, I don't get that. When I redefine as \renewcommand{\vec}{\mathnormal} I get italic non-bold font.

Comment: Then you don't get bold. Had not seen the mathnormal part of your comment